# Why does not subprocess.run() show complete result?

Tags: python, subprocess

In executing a `time` command in bash (Ubuntu 18.04, python 3.6):

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f '%E' sleep 1
0:01.00
```

It returns the meausred time as expected. But with `subprocess.run()` returns empty for the same command:

```
>>> subprocess.run("/usr/bin/time -f '%E' sleep 1", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
0:01.00
CompletedProcess(args="/usr/bin/time -f '%E' sleep 1", returncode=0, stdout=b'')
```

I'm not very familiar with the parameters of the function, and my questions are:

Why is the return from `subprocess.run()` empty?

What's the correct way to use `subprocess.run()` here?

Comment: It is most likely writing to `stderr` and not to `stdout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time` prints its results to standard error, not standard output.

You also don't need or want the shell here.

```
r = subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/time", "-f", "%E", "sleep", "1"],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    # We expect textual output
    universal_newlines=True,
    # Properly raise an error on failure
    check=True)
print(r.stderr)
```

Perhaps you should use Python's timing facilities instead, though.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188 for a somewhat extended discussion.